# Returning a Portion of the Members of a Class

Tags: vb.net, class

```
Public Function GetMedicalClassifications() As IList(Of MedicalClassification)

    Return _medicalClassifications

End Function
```

I only want to return a few of the columns (members) in MedicalClassification object instead of returning all the columns (members) as stated above.  How do I only return a couple (members) of the columns in the object?

Comment: what are the member of MedicalClassification and what are the member of MedicalClassification that you want to return?

Comment: instead of returning `_medicalClassifications` just make a IList with just the columns you need and return. You may need to change the return type.

Comment: You could create an anonymous type using LINQ if you were just using the data within the function, unfortunately you can't really return an anonymous type from a function.

Comment: What platform? WCF? Winforms?

Comment: Its a simple WINForms applicattion.

    Private _caseID As Integer
    Private _medicalID As List(Of MedicalClassification)
    Private _reviewDocumentID As List(Of ReviewDocument)
    Private _specialityDescription As String
    Private _medicalReviewDescription As String
    Private _subscriberName As String
    Private _cisdStatus As String
    Private _dueDate As Date


I want to return all but _medicalID and _reviewDocumentID.  Thanks.

Comment: too hard to read code in comment, better with the question

Comment: It's a Winform Application.

Comment: Private _caseID As Integer
    Private _medicalID As List(Of MedicalClassification)
    Private _reviewDocumentID As List(Of ReviewDocument)
    Private _specialityDescription As String
    Private _medicalReviewDescription As String
    Private _subscriberName As String
    Private _cisdStatus As String
    Private _dueDate As Date


I want to return all but _medicalID and _reviewDocumentID.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  I was trying to only to have certain columns appear in my data grid control and I thought it was best to only return the columns I wanted to the data grid control.  However, I found that I can just hide the columns on data grid to give me what I wanted.

MedicalClassificationDataGrid.Columns("MedicalClassificationID").Visible = False